# remove a value from an int array c#

Tags: c#

I have an array of int values `int[] ids`.
I have a Datatable `DataTable dt`
I want to keep only those values in the array that are there in the Datatable column ids

Say `int[] ids` contain `[2,3,4,5]`
`dt` contains `[2,3,4,3,4]` ---`ids` here may repeat

so output `ids` will have only `[2,3,4]`

Pls suggest ways with lambda or linq....

I tried the crude way using two foreachs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the intersection of the 2 collections. Linq as a Intersect method for that.

From the Linq 101 samples:

```
public void Linq50()
{
    int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
    int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };

    var commonNumbers = numbersA.Intersect(numbersB);

    Console.WriteLine("Common numbers shared by both arrays:");
    foreach (var n in commonNumbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

You can find more examples here in [Linq 101 Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#intersect1).

Answer (score 4):

use

```
int[] myIDs = (from d in dt.AsEnumerable() select d.Field<int>("id")).Intersect (ids).ToArray();
```

For reference see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#intersect1

Comment: It should be `d["id"]` instead of `dt["id"]`. In fact, I'd use `d.Field<int>("id")` to ensure that the LINQ resultset is a `IEnumerable<int>` instead of `IEnumerable<object>`. Oh, and replace `dt` by `dt.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Hey Heinzi, can we similarly do for a dictionary as well. dictionary(object, list<DateTime>)!!

Comment: @PremanshuMishra you can do something similar for `Dictionary` too but please ask a new question and describe the specific goal you want to achieve... please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new array.
Arrays are fixed size.

If you want a data structure able to remove an element you need a List.
Note that List removal operation have a worst case complexity of O(n).

For your particular problem however i would write something like this:

```
public int[] MyFunc(DataTable dt, int[] array)
{

    Set<int> allowedsIds = new Set<int>();

    Fill your set with ids you want to keep

    int[] newArray = new int[inputArray.Length];
    int newArrayCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (allowedsIds.Contains(inputArray[i]))
        {
            newArray[newArrayCount++] = inputArray[i];
        }
    }

    Array.Resize(ref newArray, newArrayCount);
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Why would List removal be O(n^2)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Intersect function:

```
        var ids = new[] {2, 3, 4, 5};
        var dt = new[] {2, 3, 4, 3, 4};

        foreach (var id in ids.Intersect(dt))
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create `List<int> fromDB` and (cycling over dataset) fill it with ids column values.
Then you could use:

```
List<int> result = ids.Intersect(fromDB).ToList();
```